# How to add ajax based autocomplete with dynamic field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to how to merge ajax autocomplete with dynamic field add input, I already have autocomplete code and work at the first field and if I add another field autocomplete doesnt work, please help

Autocomplete control code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $( "#item" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('Produk/data'); ?>",
                    data: { id_barang: $("#item").val()},
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data);
                    }    
                });
            },
        });
    });
});

$(function() {
      $("#item").change(function(){
        var nmbarang = $("#item").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo site_url('Produk/tampil_where'); ?>',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            'nmbarang': nmbarang
          },
          success: function (barang) {
            $("#harga").val(barang[0]['harga_barang']);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Dynamic field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";  
        cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 200px;" id="item" name="item[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Item"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="harga" name="harga[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Harga">  </td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="qty" name="qty[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Qty" onkeyup="findTotal(); findJumlah()">  </td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="diskon" name="diskon[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Diskon">  </td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" id="total" name="total[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Total"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" value="-" onclick="findJumlah();findTotal()"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        newRow.insertBefore("tr.isi");
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1;
    });
});
```

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already fixed , thank you everyone

```
var counter = 1;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>").data("counter",counter);
    var cols = "";  
    cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 200px;" id="item' + counter + '" name="item[' + counter + ']" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Item"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="harga' + counter + '" name="harga[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Harga">  </td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="qty' + counter + '" name="qty[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Qty" onkeyup="findTotal(); findJumlah()">  </td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="diskon' + counter + '" name="diskon[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Diskon">  </td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" id="total' + counter + '" name="total[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Total"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" value="-" onclick="findJumlah()"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    newRow.insertBefore("tr.isi");
    $("#item"+counter).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ 
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Produk/data'); ?>",
            data: { id_barang: $("#item"+counter).val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            response(data);
            }    
        });
    },
});
$("#item"+counter).change(function(){
var nmbarang = this.value;
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo site_url('Produk/tampil_where'); ?>',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
        'nmbarang': nmbarang
      },
success: function (barang) {
var cok = $("#harga"+parseFloat(counter-1)).val(barang[0]['harga_barang']);
$("#qty"+parseFloat(counter-1)).val('1');
console.log(cok);
}
});
});
    counter++;
});

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
    // counter -= 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    (document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $( "#item" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({ 
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('Produk/data'); ?>",
                            data: { id_barang: $("#item").val()},
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(data){
                                response(data);
                            }    
                        });
                    },
                });
            });
        });

    $(function() {
          $("#item").change(function(){
            var nmbarang = $("#item").val();
            $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo site_url('Produk/tampil_where'); ?>',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                'nmbarang': nmbarang
              },
              success: function (barang) {
//dont't mention id.put class of that dynamic textbox for autocomplete
                $(".harga").val(barang[0]['harga_barang']);
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: Please try adding some details to your answer

Comment: sure,listen whenever you are binding data to dynamic textbox without knowing their IDs,then we should have to set by the class name of that dyanamic textbox.one more thing we have to set the class for all textboxes as same.

Comment: my dynamic textbox have no class if want use name how ??

Comment: we have to put a class name for the dynamic textbox.<td><input type="text" style="width: 200px;" id="item" class="csItem" name="item[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Item">

Comment: $(".csItem").val(barang[0]['harga_barang']);

Comment: you miss the point, my code above is work only first textbox and i want ask how to merge 2 code above can work with my autocomplete